# Number wrong in the Table of content

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, page-numbering

I have a problem with the ToC numbering in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\usepackage[]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots of table of content
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\bf} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{10pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-0.5em}}%


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{AUTHOR'S  DECLARATION}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
\include{abstract}
\clearpage
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF ABBRAVIATIONS}

\clearpage
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1em plus 1pt}}%

\chapter[CHAPTER ONE INTRODUCTION]{CHAPTER ONE\\INTRODUCTION}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
sfsdfsf
sfsdfsf
\section{first section}
This is section one in chapter one.
\section{second section }
This is section two  in chapter one.

\chapter[CHAPTER TWO RELATED WORK]{CHAPTER TWO \\RELATED WORD}
\section{first section}
This is section one in chapter TWO.
\section{second section }
This is section two  in chapter TWO.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to indent the code by four spaces to make it look as code on these sites. Please press edit on your question and see it is formatted. Also please try and make a MWE, your showcase is by far not minimal.

Comment: Your life would be much easier if using a KOMA-class (e.g. scrreprt).

Comment: What exactly is wrong? We don't have `abstract.tex`, but apart from that I don't see any problem.

Comment: @user1873093 What do you mean with "a problem with the ToC numbering"? Can you explain this a bit further? When I translate your code, the TOC looks pretty messed up in terms of line spacing.